# Updating 2d array through scanner

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java, and programming in general. I recently started working with arrays, and came upon an exercise in the book that i thought id give a try. The goal is to read a file  using the scanner class assign each number to a different cell in a 2d array. This is what i have for the method. But no matter how i change it, i cant seem to get the desired result. Either i end up getting the last number in every cell, or i get an error. Please help.

```
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
while (A[row][col] != -1)
{
for (row = 0; row < A.length; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < A[row].length; col++)
        A[row][col] = scan.nextInt();   
        }
}
```

Comment: As it is you're inserting the same number into every column of every row, over and over. What is it you're trying to do? `assign each number to a different cell in a 2d array` is kinda ... vague.

Comment: I'm trying to read in several values from a file using scanner, and insert each number into a cell, until a -1 is read which is when the while loop is supposed to stop filling the table.

Answer (score 3):

The scanning needs to happen in the inner-most loop. At this point, you might want to re-read the chapter you're on and spend a bit longer working on problems before posting to SO.

```
...

for (int col = 0; col < A[row].length; col++){
   A[row][col] = temp;
   temp = scan.nextInt();
}
...
```

You might also find that printing out values is useful while watching programs execute. Add `System.out.println(temp)` after the point where you read in `temp`. This would have made the problem obvious. You'll also want to change your `while` looping construct. As of now, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: hey, i tried what you said before i posted, but when i do that, I get a noSuchElementException. I went ahead and tried to fix the while loop as well but didn't do anything. you can see the edited code above. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments ... this should do what you're asking. The problem you're having is that you're not able to break out of your inner loop without having some sort of conditional on the outer one.

Note that I changed `A` to `a`; variables should never start with uppercase.

```
int a[][] = new int[20][20];
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
int current = 0;
for (row = 0; row < a.length, current != -1; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++)
    {
         try
         {
             current = scan.nextInt();           
             if (current == -1)
             {
                 break;
             }
             else
             {
                 a[row][col] = current;   
             }
         }
         catch ( NoSuchElementException e)
         {
             System.out.println("I hit the end of the file without finding -1!");
             current = -1;
             break;
         }
         catch ( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
         {
                System.out.println("I ran out of space in my 2D array!");
                current = -1;
                break;
         }
     }
}
```

I personally wouldn't use the nested loops, and go this route:

```
int a[][] = new int[20][20];
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
int current = 0;

while (scan.hasNextInt())
{
    current = scan.nextInt();
    if (current == -1)
    {
        break;
    }

    a[row][col] = current;
    col++;
    if (col == a[row].length)
    {
        row++;
        col = 0;

        if (row == a.length)
        {
            System.out.println("I ran out of space in my 2D array!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, learn that `if(...)` should always be followed by `{ ... } `. The same goes for `else`. That just helps. anyway +1 for your answer :)

Comment: @dantuch - I understand the risks of someone coming after and screwing up a conditional when adding additional code. That being said ... sometimes I just don't feel like it ;) Fair point for when showing a new programmer how to do something though, I'll edit. (Though I could argue that people should simply pay attention to these things when adding code since it's a valid construct ... )